# How to make iOS universal link work with Gmail app

Tags: ios-universal-links

We have implemented iOS universal links that open pages within our mobile app.  The links in the format of appname://abc/xyz work when clicked in an app such as Slack, but fail to work in the most updated version of the Gmail app.

I note that the Branch documentation says "If you open a Universal Link in one of these apps, it should work correctly all the time." and it lists Gmail.

So is it Gmail, or is there something maybe that has to implemented differently for the links to work with Gmail vs Slack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in the format `appname://abc/xyz` are actually URI Schemes, NOT Universal Links. Universal links use the scheme `http` or `https`. Gmail does not open apps via URI schemes so you'll have to [set up universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).

Comment: Helpful response and we will now implement universal links which will also require us to set up dynamic web pages to serve up the links on devices that don't have the app installed.

Comment: You could set this up through [Branch](https://docs.branch.io) since they will host the webpages for you and will get you out of having to have an associated website.